# AbstractAPI GeoLocation IP | codeigniter Call to a member function getIPAddress() on null

Tags: php

I try integrate  geo location ip this library Abstractapi  with codeigniter 3:

```
https://github.com/abstractapi/php-ip-geolocation
```

I install this via composer, then I copy  files from root vendor to `application/libraries/abstractipgeolocation/vendor/`

Then I create controller and call:

```
require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/abstractipgeolocation/vendor/autoload.php');

use Abstractapi\IpGeolocation\AbstractIpGeolocation;
use Abstractapi\IpGeolocation\Common\Exception\AbstractHttpErrorException;
```

now in controller I add function and load to view coupons:

```
public function coupons()
    {
        $this->check_vendor_permission();
        $this->load->model('coupon_model');
        $data['title'] = trans("coupons");
        $data['description'] = trans("coupons") . " - " . $this->app_name;
        $data['keywords'] = trans("coupons") . "," . $this->app_name;

        $data['num_rows'] = $this->coupon_model->get_coupons_count($this->auth_user->id);
        $pagination = $this->paginate(generate_dash_url("coupons"), $data['num_rows'], $this->per_page);
        $data['coupons'] = $this->coupon_model->get_coupons_paginated($this->auth_user->id, $pagination['per_page'], $pagination['offset']);
        
        try {
            // build required data
            $formData = http_build_query([
                'api_key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                'ip_address' => $this->request->getIPAddress()
            ]);
            // make curl request to abstractapi.com to get ip information
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => "https://ipgeolocation.abstractapi.com/v1/?" . $formData,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    "accept: application/json",
                    "cache-control: no-cache",
                    "content-type: application/json",
                ),
            ));
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            $err = curl_error($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            if ($err) {
                $data = [
                    'status' => false,
                    'message' => $err
                ];
            } else {
                $response = json_decode($response, true);
                $data = [
                    'status' => true,
                    'ipv4' => $response['ip_address'] ?? '',
                    'ipv6' => $this->request->getIPAddress() ?? '',
                    'isp_name' => $response['connection']['isp_name'] ?? 'Unknown',
                    'isp_city' => $response['city'] ?? 'Unknown',
                    'isp_region' => $response['region'] ?? 'Unknown',
                    'isp_country' => $response['country'] ?? 'Unknown',
                    'isp_lat' => $response['latitude'] ?? 0,
                    'isp_lng' => $response['longitude'] ?? 0,
                ];
            }
            return view('welcome_message', $data);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }

        $this->load->view('dashboard/includes/_header', $data);
        $this->load->view('dashboard/coupon/coupons', $data);
        $this->load->view('dashboard/includes/_footer');
    }
```

Now in view coupons.php I try get country:

```
<section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row info mt-5 p-5 rounded">
                <?=
                $status ?
                '<div class="col-md-8">
                    <p id="p-text">My IP Address is:</p>
                    <p class="ip-address">
                        IPv4:
                        <span class="fa fa-question" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="The most common IP version assigned by ISPs."></span>
                        <span id="ipv4">' . $ipv4 . '</span>
                    </p>
 
                    <p class="ip-address">
                        IPv6:
                        <span class="fa fa-question" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="The IP version assigned by routers and other devices that do not support IPv4."></span>
                        <span id="ipv6"> '.$ipv6. '</span>
                    </p>
 
                    <p class="mt-6">
                    <p id="p-text">My IP Information:</p>
                    <p class="isp-address">
                        ISP:
                        <span id="ipv4"> ' . $isp_name . ' </span> <br><br>
 
                        City:
                        <span id="ipv4">' . $isp_city . ' </span> <br><br>
 
                        Region:
                        <span id="ipv4">' . $isp_region . '</span> <br><br>
 
                        Country:
                        <span id="ipv4">' . $isp_country . ' </span>
 
                    </p>
 
                    </p>
 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div style="height: 253px;" id="map">
                    </div>
                </div>'
                :
                '<p> Could not find your IP Address. </p>'
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

But after this I get:

```
Message: Undefined property: Dashboard_controller::$request

Filename: controllers/Dashboard_controller.php

Type: Error

Message: Call to a member function getIPAddress() on null

Filename: public_html/application/controllers/Dashboard_controller.php

Line Number: 920
```

line 920:

```
'ip_address' => $this->request->getIPAddress()
```

Can anyone help me from where this error come and how to resolve?

Comment: The error message is saying that `$this->request` is null.

Comment: One way to resolve is to put a question mark `?`  in front of the arrow `->` in current PHP versions: `'ip_address' => $this->request?->getIPAddress()` - [the `?->` nullsafe operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.nullsafe) is making the method call _"null safe"_. Instead of crashing `'ip_address'` will safely assigned the `null` (non-)value.